# Calling geometry methods in react-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

How to call methods like .rotateZ (doesn't work out of the box) or .center (which accept no args) on geometry component.

```
<mesh position={[x, y, 0]}>
    <shapeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[shape]} rotateZ={3.14} />
    <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color={'#FF0000'} />
</mesh>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you [looked into `useRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)? It stores a reference to that object so you can call methods on it as needed:

```js
const geomRef = useRef();
const onButtonClick = () => {
    // You might need to use .current
    geomRef.current.rotateZ(Math.PI / 2);
}
```

Then you can add this reference to the object you want to point to:

```jsx
<mesh position={[x, y, 0]}>
    <shapeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[shape]} ref={geomRef} />
    <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color={'#FF0000'} />
</mesh>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the onUpdate prop to center my custom geometry and rotate

```
<shapeBufferGeometry args={[shape]} onUpdate={geometry => {  
    geometry.center()
    geometry.rotateX(Math.PI / 2)
    }} />
```